# parameter not being passed between controller and service

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, postman, backend

I have some very simple code that I want to get down to understand the concept:

controller.js:

```
router.get('/retrieve-sound-id', retrieveSoundID);

module.exports = router;

async function retrieveSoundID(req, res, next) {
    const customer_id = req.body['customer-id'];
    const file_name = req.body['file-name'];
    
    fileService.retrieveSoundID(customer_id, file_name).then(function(val) {
        res.send(val);
    });
}
```

service.js:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

module.exports = {
    retrieveSoundID
};

function retrieveSoundID({ customer_id, file_name  }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(file_name)
  });
}
```

Data in postman:

```
{
    "customer-id": 1,
    "file-name": "Bob"
}
```

When I make the API call, it returns successfully but there is no output in terminal or postman. What am I doing wrong? It seems like it is returning undefined.

**UPDATE**

controller:

```
router.get('/retrieve-sound-id', retrieveSoundID);

module.exports = router;

async function retrieveSoundID(req, res, next) {
    
    fileService.retrieveSoundID(req.body).then(function(val) {
        res.send(val);
    });
}
```

service:

```
    function retrieveSoundID({ data }) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    console.log(data);

 }

}
```

**This returns undefined**

Comment: read about destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an object as you're expected in the `retrieveSoundID`:

```
fileService.retrieveSoundID({ customer_id, file_name }).then(function(val) {
    res.send(val);
});
```

instead of passing 2 arguments, you just pass an object with the `customer_id` and `file_name` properties

**UPDATE:**

You need to pass a data object to the `retrieveSoundID` function, as it expects a data object:

```
    fileService.retrieveSoundID({ data: req.body}).then(function(val) {
    res.send(val);
});
```

Comment: checkout my update! still having issues. thanks for your support!

Comment: Both of your questions seems really related to how to pass objects as arguments to functions, with and without destructuring. If my answer its ok to your question please mark it as replied